Representations of a reductive Lie group vie central character and K-types
Let $G$ be a real reductive group, let $\widehat G$ denote the unitary dual and $\widehat G_{adm}\supset\widehat G$ be the admissible dual, i.e., the set of isomorphy classes of irreducible Harish-Chandra modules.
Let $\mathbb D$ denote the algebra of bi-invariant differential operators and let $\mathbb{D}^*=\mathrm{Hom}_{alg}(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ for some $n$. On each $\pi\in\widehat G_{adm}$ the operators in $\mathbb D$ acts by scalars, so $\pi$ determines a point $\chi_\pi\in\mathbb{C}^n$, whose coordinates are the eigenvalues of the generators of $\mathbb D$. Further fix a maximal compact subgroup $K$. Then each $\tau\in\widehat K$ occurs with a finite multiplicity in $\pi|_K$, so for any subset $F\subset\widehat K$, the representation  $\pi$ defines an element of the discrete set $D_F=\prod_{\tau\in F}\mathbb{N}_0$. Together we get a map $$
P_F:\widehat G_{adm}\to\mathbb{C}^n\ \times\ D_F.
$$
My questions are:

If $F=\widehat K$, is $P$ injective?
For a given bounded set $B\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, is it true that there exists a finite set $F\subset\widehat K$ such that $P_F$ is injective on $P_\emptyset^{-1}(B)$?


Perhaps it worth noting that for tempered representations with real infinitesimal character, the answer to your Question 1 is "yes".  One can classify such representations by the smallest $K$-type.  This is a theorem of Vogan.  It is cited in this recent preprint, as Theorem 1.1: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.01004.pdf I am not enough of a representation theorist to know how this result changes when one replaces "tempered" by "unitary" in your question.

@Joseph: Thanks, that helps.
